# Finding pitch when there is only one pitched sound?

Tags: python, audio, ipython

I'm using iPython to find the pitch of a WAV file where there is only one pitch sound. My approach is to find the fundamental frequency and its harmonics. Then use those values in some way to calculate the pitch. My method for find the fundamental is to find all of the indexes to the peak frequncies then store them in an array. Is my approach wrong? And how what do i do since im wav files only have one pitched sound. I've managed to find all the components but im unsure how to use them to find the fundamental. Or should I use the periodic time and try and find the highest frequency with that period.

```
def getPitchInHz(filename):
    file3 = wavReadMono(filename)
    play(file3)
    spec = abs(fft.fft(file3)) #compute the magnitude spectrum
    rate = 44100 #44100 Hz
    freqs = fft.fftfreq(size(spec))*rate #array of frequencies corresponding to bins
    Spec = spec[0:size(spec)/2] #spectrum up to the Nyquist
    duration = size(Spec)/rate
    #periodic time = 1/frequency
    pt = 1/freqs
    t = arange(0, duration, 1/rate) #t is an array of equally-spaced time points
    #plot(t[0:size(spec)/2], spec[0:size(spec)/2])
    harmonics = 5
    i = 0
    plot(freqs[0:6000], Spec[0:6000]) #
    xlabel("Frequency, Hz") 
    ylabel("Magnitude") 
    #v = []
    #print "Fundamental frequency approx. ", freqs[peakIndex], "Hz"
    print "Duration", duration
    print "The length of the spectrum is ", size(Spec)

    while i < harmonics:
        peakIndex = argmax(Spec)#find index for peak frequency
        if peakIndex in v: #if index is already in array do 
            Spec[peakIndex] = 0 #Set this peak to zero so that we can use argmax to find the next highest:
        else:
            v[i] = peakIndex #then add index to array
            i+1
    for x in range( len(v)):#loop through array of index starting with the peak frequency that occurs earliet
        print "harmonic ", x , "     Frequency ", freqs[v[x]], "Hz        ", abs(Spec[v[x]]), "magnitude"

    return pitch
```

Comment: OK, and what's not working about that? What is your actual problem?

Comment: @kindall ive updated my question. my code finds the frequency that are right next to each other instead of the harmonically across. and im not saw how to check that the one i have is the fundamental/

Comment: try applying a window function and google spectral leakage.